# How to block a specific content using squid?

Tags: linux, internet, squid

My problem is a bit strange.
In Iran there is a famous "access denied page" that redirects you to a strange page with a lot of HTML errors and lol, telling you RTFM about ridiculous Internet laws.
I want to filter the contents of the page, because the page IP, URL, ... are all unknown.
I don't know much about squid configuration scripts.I can read but cannot write:(
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/squid-content-filter-block-files/

To block things other than file extensions, just replace the regexes in `blocks.files.acl` with the block regexes you want to use.